# changing the substr functionality with java 8 style

Tags: java

In the below method I am reading the invoice id and remove the first three initial characters and then after checking if it contains dollar I am also removing them. My question is if I can do the same in java 8?

```
public static String removID(String invoiceId) {
    String deviceSerialNo = null;
    if(invoiceId != null && invoiceId.length() == 15) {
        invoiceIdSerialNo = invoiceId.substring(3);
        if(invoiceIdSerialNo.contains("$")) {
            invoiceIdSerialNo = invoiceIdSerialNo.replace("$", "");
        }
    }
    return invoiceIdSerialNo;

}
```

Comment: I am unsure. What exactly is your question?

Comment: *"after checking it contains hyphen"* but code is `contains("$")`. A dollar sign ($) is not the same as a hyphen (-).

Comment: In what way is this not "Java 8 style"?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean "lambda expressions" when you say "Java 8 style", you can do it using [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

```
public static String shrinkDeviceID(String deviceId) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(deviceId)
            .filter(s -> s.length() == 15)
            .map(s -> s.substring(3).replace("$", ""))
            .orElse(null);
}
```